# How do I prevent log4cplus log messages within log messages?

Tags: log4cplus

I have the following (simplified) code in my C++ program:

```
std::string DataRequest::toString() const {
LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(logger,
        LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("symbol=" << m_contract.symbol));

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "id=" << reqId
    << ",symbol=" << m_contract.symbol;
return oss.str();
}
```

and

```
int DataService::requestData(
    DataRequest request) {

LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("requestData: " << request.toString()));
}
```

This code then produces the log message:

```
TRACE symbol=AAA
INFO  symbol=AAArequestData: id=1,symbol=AAA
```

however I was expecting

```
TRACE symbol=AAA
INFO  requestData: id=1,symbol=AAA
```

Since there is a log4cplus message being generated within a log4cplus message it appears to be concatenating the two messages into a single message.  Is this normal behaviour?  Is there a solution to force each message to be generated independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong code

```
LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(logger,
        LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("symbol=" << m_contract.symbol));
```

it should read

```
LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(logger,
        LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("symbol=") << m_contract.symbol);
```

instead.

As for the concatenated messages, what output layout are you using? If it is the pattern layout, then you should add the `%n` formatter at the very end of the format string.

**EDIT:**

> Unfortunately I am still getting the having the problem that the log
>   messages are being concatenated. I think this has to do with the fact
>   that the call request.toString() in the log message itself also has a
>   call to a log message but for some reason the two messages are being
>   printed together even after the code fix. :(

Ah, I misunderstood the problem, initially. So, you are logging a second event while you are preparing first. The issue is that the formatting is done to a thread-local `ostringstream`. The thread-local `ostringstream` is used as a performance enhancement. (The `ostringstream` does not have to be constructed and destructed on each logged message.)

For immediate work around, you have two options. First, you stop this nested logging. Second,  you "fix" `LOG4CPLUS_*()` macros to not use the thread-local `ostringstream` or you roll your own logging macros. Either should not be that hard.

Long term, I can add a special case to the logging macros that would make them use fresh `ostringstream` each time to allow your use case.

**EDIT 2:**

I have filled a bug report and attached a patch that implements a work-around. See https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/bugs/153/.

Comment: I am using `log4cplus.appender.LogFile.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout` and `log4cplus.appender.LogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%q} %-5p [%T] [%c{2}] [%l] [%M] %x - %m %n`.  All of my other log messages are being printed correctly.  It is just the one case above in which a call to a function which also has a log message causes the two messages to be concatenated. I'll try again with the code fix you suggested to see if that might fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the having the problem that the log messages are being concatenated. I think this has to do with the fact that the call `request.toString()` in the log message itself also has a call to a log message but for some reason the two messages are being printed together even after the code fix. :(

Comment: @kmccoy: I have implemented a work-around, see the bug report linked in the answer.